# Calculate circle coordinates in a sequential fashion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

I need to have all point coordinates for a given circle one after another, so I can make an object go in circles by hopping from one point to the next. I tried the Midpoint circle algorithm, but the version I found is meant to draw and the coordinates are not sequential. They are produced simultaneously for 8 quadrants and in opposing directions on top of that. If at least they were in the same direction, I could make a separate array for every quadrant and append them to one another at the end. This is the JavaScript adapted code I have now:

```
  function calcCircle(centerCoordinates, radius) {
    var coordinatesArray = new Array();
    // Translate coordinates
    var x0 = centerCoordinates.left;
    var y0 = centerCoordinates.top;
    // Define variables
    var f = 1 - radius;
    var ddFx = 1;
    var ddFy = -radius << 1;
    var x = 0;
    var y = radius;
    coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0, y0 + radius));
    coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0, y0 - radius));
    coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 + radius, y0));
    coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 - radius, y0));
    // Main loop
    while (x < y) {
      if (f >= 0) {
        y--;
        ddFy += 2;
        f += ddFy;
      }
      x++;
      ddFx += 2;
      f += ddFx;
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 + x, y0 + y));
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 - x, y0 + y));
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 + x, y0 - y));
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 - x, y0 - y));
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 + y, y0 + x));
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 - y, y0 + x));
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 + y, y0 - x));
      coordinatesArray.push(new Coordinates(x0 - y, y0 - x));
    }
    // Return the result
    return coordinatesArray;
  }
```

I prefer some fast algorithm without trigonometry, but any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

This is the final solution. Thanks everybody!

```
  function calcCircle(centerCoordinates, radius) {
    var coordinatesArray = new Array();
    var octantArrays =
      {oct1: new Array(), oct2: new Array(), oct3: new Array(), oct4: new Array(),
       oct5: new Array(), oct6: new Array(), oct7: new Array(), oct8: new Array()};
    // Translate coordinates
    var xp = centerCoordinates.left;
    var yp = centerCoordinates.top;
    // Define add coordinates to array
    var setCrd =
      function (targetArray, xC, yC) {
        targetArray.push(new Coordinates(yC, xC));
      };
    // Define variables
    var xoff = 0;
    var yoff = radius;
    var balance = -radius;
    // Main loop
    while (xoff <= yoff) {
      // Quadrant 7 - Reverse
      setCrd(octantArrays.oct7, xp + xoff, yp + yoff);
      // Quadrant 6 - Straight
      setCrd(octantArrays.oct6, xp - xoff, yp + yoff);
      // Quadrant 3 - Reverse
      setCrd(octantArrays.oct3, xp - xoff, yp - yoff);
      // Quadrant 2 - Straight
      setCrd(octantArrays.oct2, xp + xoff, yp - yoff);
      // Avoid duplicates
      if (xoff != yoff) {
        // Quadrant 8 - Straight
        setCrd(octantArrays.oct8, xp + yoff, yp + xoff);
        // Quadrant 5 - Reverse
        setCrd(octantArrays.oct5, xp - yoff, yp + xoff);
        // Quadrant 4 - Straight
        setCrd(octantArrays.oct4, xp - yoff, yp - xoff);
        // Quadrant 1 - Reverse
        setCrd(octantArrays.oct1, xp + yoff, yp - xoff);
      }
      // Some weird stuff
      balance += xoff++ + xoff;
      if (balance >= 0) {
        balance -= --yoff + yoff;
      }
    }
    // Reverse counter clockwise octant arrays
    octantArrays.oct7.reverse();
    octantArrays.oct3.reverse();
    octantArrays.oct5.reverse();
    octantArrays.oct1.reverse();
    // Remove counter clockwise octant arrays last element (avoid duplicates)
    octantArrays.oct7.pop();
    octantArrays.oct3.pop();
    octantArrays.oct5.pop();
    octantArrays.oct1.pop();
    // Append all arrays together
    coordinatesArray =
      octantArrays.oct4.concat(octantArrays.oct3).concat(octantArrays.oct2).concat(octantArrays.oct1).
        concat(octantArrays.oct8).concat(octantArrays.oct7).concat(octantArrays.oct6).concat(octantArrays.oct5);
    // Return the result
    return coordinatesArray;
  }
```

Comment: If you are going to move an object on a circular path in a browser then the LAST of your concerns should be about the speed of sin/cos.

Comment: I am going to precаlculate the coordinates that the object is going to use for exactly this reason and the object is actually a lot of objects. So speed of sin/cos CAN BE a concern. Especially with IE on а Netbook.

Comment: The other drawback with sin/cos is that it generates a finite number of points. As the radius of the circle increases the apparent velocity of the item being rendered will increase if the number of points being calculated remains the same (because their spacing on the circumference increases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can try the following approach: use the algorithm you gave but push your coordinates to eight different coordinateArrays. Afterwards you have to reverse half of them (those with (x0+x,y0-y), (x0-x,y0+y), (x0+y,y0+x), (x0-y,y0-x)) and afterwards append all arrays in the correct order. Take care that you add the first four points to the correct arrays.

Comment: I thought of that too. I beat you to it, but I still give you the credit ;) Another solution would be to calculate the entite circle instead of only one octant, but I don't know how to adapt the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot do it without trigonometry, but it works pretty fast for me. Sorry I'm not familiar with Java, so I write the code in VB:

```
Dim PointList As New List(Of PointF)
For angle = 0 To Math.PI * 2 Step 0.01
    'the smaller the step, the more points you get
    PointList.Add(New PointF(Math.Cos(angle) * r + x0, Math.Sin(angle) * r + y0))
Next
```

x0 and y0 are the center coordinates of the circle, r is the radius.

Hope I answered your question.

Comment: I wonder how this can work without at least the circle's radius.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript implementation based on Dave's answer. A bit over-engineered, I wanted to avoid calling sin and cos more than necessary. Ironically making use of Dave's first answer without the radius :)

```
function calculateCircle(x,y,radius) {

  var basicPoints = getBasicCircle();
  var i = basicPoints.length;
  var points = []; // don't change basicPoints: that would spoil the cache.
  while (i--) {
    points[i] = {
      x: x + (radius * basicPoints[i].x),
      y: y + (radius * basicPoints[i].y)
    };
  }
  return points;
}

function getBasicCircle() {
  if (!arguments.callee.points) {
    var points = arguments.callee.points = [];
    var end = Math.PI * 2;
    for (var angle=0; angle < end; angle += 0.1) {
      points.push({x: Math.sin(angle), 
                   y: Math.cos(angle)
                  });
    }
  }
  return arguments.callee.points
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hemlock! Care to explain what you did in more detail? Using some king of precalculated circle and then expanding for different radiuses? This will no do well if the points are not enough for a big circle?

Comment: Yeah, it pre-calculates a 1 radius circle. You would have to change the caching function if you wanted to return circles with higher or lower resolution.