# Making a foreground image transparent within a radius around the cursor

Tags: jquery, html, transparency, html5-canvas

We have a design we need to implement where the concept is the user is shining a flashlight on an object and anything within the flashlight' beam (a circle around the cursor) should show the background image instead of the foreground image.

I'm looking on suggestions for how to implement ideally using jQuery and HTML5 techniques. I'm quite sure we could achieve this with Flash but we want it to be iOS friendly.

Comment: You'll probably have to import the image into a `canvas` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images.  Beyond that, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two html canvases.

The foreground would be a canvas with a higher z-index than the background and they would both be position:absolute and be contained by a container element.

Then you would find the location of a circle centered around the mouse (see resources)

You would get it's position by using the mouse move event and subtracting half the height and width of the circle from the location of the mouse to center it around the mouse.

Then you could manipulate the pixels on the canvas that have the same coordinates as the circle to have an alpha value of 0 (or a number between 0 and 1 if you don't want it to be completely transparent)

Hopefully that explains it thoroughly enough. Feel free to ask any questions. I'm not going to just hand out code though because that's not the point of this forum really.

Resources:

Basics:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-tutorials-introduction/

Get coordinates of a circle:
[Calculate circle coordinates in a sequential fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700404/calculate-circle-coordinates-in-a-sequential-fashion)

Manipulate Pixels:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/pixels.html

Comment: In terms of major browser support, would this work on everything but IE8 and earlier?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csPcb/2/) where you cover the background instead of using a mask. I used a rudimentary png to simulate your flashligh, you should use a better image off course

Beware of sluggish performance on jsfiddle but should be much better anywhere else

UPDATE: Update jsfiddle link to fix an error

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The issue with that is it seems the foreground image needs to move to make this work. We need both the background and foreground image to stay static and the cursor area to reveal the background image.

Comment: Is there any special requirement for it to be static?

BTW you want this behavior for cursors and you also say you need this for iOS devices. How do you intent to use a cursor for iOS?

Comment: The design calls for the images to be static. The flashlight is like an x-ray revealing what's underneath. 
On the cursor for iOS point, that's a very good point... With finger dragging you can't illuminate around the finger because their finger would be over the thing you're displaying. So we'd have to do the finger dragging at the bottom right of the illuminated circle and provide some kind of cue so they know to try dragging their finger.

Comment: I'm no html export for mobile browser but even with finger dragging, iOS behaves like scrolling, not mouse moving. Don't know how you intend to overcome this